# Render HTML in Canvas/WebGL

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webgl

Is it possible to render HTML elements in Canvas or WebGL? (similar to how one can draw a video element texture in WebGL)

Answer (score 13):

There is an attempt that can do the work near 80%. Fail to render dropdownlist, buttons and some more, but mostly items from the page are rendered.

See and download it from here.

http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

also

http://hertzen.com/experiments/jsfeedback/

Answer (score 5):

You should also check out http://robert.ocallahan.org/2011/11/drawing-dom-content-to-canvas.html

It might throw a security error in Chrome but works fine in Firefox.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's currently not possible, not yet.
But it is planned to include this functionality as pointed out in [a video from 3rd WebGL Camp (at about 6:44)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6YYFsmjCKX4&feature=player_detailpage#t=403s).

Comment: I don't believe there are any concrete plans to expose rendering HTML to either a canvas or a texture except for privileged JS (ie: Extensions) as it would be a big security issue

Comment: As is said in the video (by the guy from Google) there are (or were, 8 months ago) plans for that. I didn't follow this thread as everything I currently need is already there.

Comment: I sit next to that guy ;-)  There are no plans for an unprivileged version of that extensions that I know of

Answer (score 3):

I just thought I'd add why.

This is the same issue as dirty canvases and the timing attack that was fixed soon after WebGL shipped

With canvas 2d you can draw images into the canvas with `ctx.drawImage(someImage, ...)`;  The problem comes from cross domain images. Normally JavaScript can not read the pixels inside an image. It can read the pixels inside a canvas. So, to get the pixels from an image you first draw the image to the canvas then read the pixels from the canvas `ctx.getImageData(...)`

This is a security problem for cross domain images (images from domains other than the domain of the page).

The solution for canvas 2d is the moment you draw a cross domain image into a 2d canvas that canvas is internally marked as *dirty* and both `ctx.getImageData` and `canvas.toDataURL` will throw a security error.

Originally WebGL followed the same rule. If you called `gl.texImageXXX` with a cross domain image or a dirty canvas the webgl canvas would be marked as *dirty* and `gl.readPixels` as well as `canvas.toDataURL` would not work.

Smart people pointed out that in the case of WebGL this was not enough because even if you couldn't call `gl.readPixels` you could design a shader that takes more time based on the colors of the textures it's accessing. Using that you could time how long it takes to access the pixels of a texture and effectively reconstitute the contents of the image.

The solution was that WebGL doesn't allow cross origin images by default. Instead, you have to request CORS (cross origin resource sharing) permission from the other server. Only if it grants permission can WebGL use the image.

Okay, after all that hopefully you can see why you can't render HTML into WebGL. If you could render HTML a canvas then you could use the above techniques to read the contents of that HTML including embedded iframes etc, dirty canvases, images from other domains, etc...

Comment: And I still don't get why cross origin images are a security issue to begin with, what's the deal there? How serious are those issues and what should someone do if they happen to stumble upon any other "creative workarounds"?

Comment: Maybe this Q&A? https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8264/why-is-the-same-origin-policy-so-important

Comment: No sorry I don't see any connection. They are making some absurd claims that accessing other tabs is apparently really easy which I thought is really hard. And also absurd claims that...if I understand correctly...even if you have the URL of an img you should only be able to display it to the user but not know anything about it from JS if it comes from another domain without CORS. Is this correct? If I can know anything about it we are all going to die in some horrible InfoSec nightmare?

Comment: Maybe you should google it or ask that question yourself instead of doing it in comments? Here's another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020259/why-cors-on-images-with-html-canvas

Comment: I have been grappling with the same questions @Winchestro.  In addition you can still make requests to servers that would be evil, anyway.  XSS mitigation feels very strange in situations like these.  Evil code running on compromised sites can transmit any data they want back to their evil servers in the current implementation.  If you ever develop a deeper understanding about the applicability here, please post about it.

Answer (score 2):

Use this library https://github.com/PixelsCommander/HTML-GL it is as easy as wrap your content with `<html-gl>` tag.