# Making screenshot of the website with changes made by user

Tags: php, javascript, html, screenshot

Is it possible to take a screenshot of the visible part of the website *directly as it is seen by user* (rendered by by the browser), including any changes made by user (e.g. moved divs, text typed in forms etc.)?

---

So you open a website, where you can make changes to its content. And there's a button (on the website of course), when you click it, the actual visible part of the website with all the changes you made is saved as an image and for example there goes a popup window where you can type in an email to send this image to, or something like that. Javascript, php, html5 or anything else? Old browsers and ie doesn't matter.
I've searched a lot for the answer, read lots of related articles, but I couldn't find the solution, cause what I need is not the script that would re-render the page like html2canvas, but capture the actual content displayed on the screen.
Any ideas and comments are much appreciated!

Comment: check  [Taking Website Screenshots via PHP](http://forrst.com/posts/Taking_Website_Screenshots_via_PHP-aNP)

Comment: A very restricted option is a Chrome extension, which allows you to do this.

Comment: No... not EXACTLY as the user sees it.  Each browser renders the webpage differently (font variations, spacing, css3 and html 5).  You can use an extension or plugin to get the job done, but again, not exact.

Comment: Guys, I don't want some app or script to render the page, I want the part of the user's screen where the site is displayed to be converted into image. **Not the code of the page, but the pixels of the screen**, that's what I'm talking about!

Comment: We at [usersnap.com](http://usersnap.com) are using a special technique in our rendering engine to solve that problem to render the exact content of the users browser in every browser!

Answer (score 0):

This is something that can be extremely tricky.

Essentially your only option of doing this *in browser* with no extensions or such is to try rendering HTML into the `<canvas>` tag.

There are several projects which do that, most reliable choices are noted in this SO question's answers: [Render HTML in Canvas/WebGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335383/render-html-in-canvas-webgl)

Note that none of the projects are 100% accurate, but a canvas can be rendered into an image and thus could be saved or emailed by the user like you asked.

Comment: I understand that it won't be an easy thing to do. 
But would it include the changes made to the content of the page or render the default code?

Comment: It would include changes since you can give the renderer the most recent DOM (eg. after the user did any changes).

Comment: Well, thanks, I'll check it out then. Hope I'll be able to understand all that staff(: