# Why CORS on Images with HTML Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, cors

Recently, I spent a bit of time researching a solution to a rather common problem in web development- I was dealing with logos middle-aligned on a transparent background, but having to place text below them, it would then appear as though the amount of whitespace between the text and the image shifts from page to page. After a bit of research, I discovered I could re-align the images bottom-left using a canvas, and the solution worked beautifully... at least until I integrated the solution into our code-base and discovered it was failing with:

"Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data." (Say what!?)

Looking into it, the offending code was located at the first line of the following function:

```
getColumn: function (context, x, y, imageHeight) {
    var arr = context.getImageData(x, y, 1, imageHeight).data; //<-- CORS HATES THIS!
    return pvt.normalizeRGBArray(arr)
}
```

Now, I understand perfectly well what the CORS standard is, and I know the solution to this problem. The server needs to support CORS first. Either the server can set the http header access-control-allow-origin: "*", or allow a developer to set the crossDomain attribute for the image to "anonymous"/"use-credentials". This is all fine and dandy except when you work on the front-end for a big company where convincing the server-lords to change anything related to security is a non-starter conversation.

So really, my question here is what IS the logic behind having this security error occur with images on a canvas? They are frickin' images for crying out loud! It is fine to download them, hot-link to them, use them in memory, but "oh no!" don't manipulate them in any way whatsoever, or CORS throws an error!

If you ask me, the image is not tainted, it's this hairbrained CORS standard that is. Can somebody please explain the logic for why this happens? How could using a canvas to manipulate an image possibly be a security concern?

Comment: As someone who once worked for an advertising company, you'd be surprised what kinds of things you can slip into images. But as a simple example, since you haven't established trust between the two parties, someone could be slipping you porn when you expect cats.

Comment: Okay, but still any 3rd party code can do that without needing to use a canvas... document.body.appendChild(img). As long as the code is allowed on there...

Comment: browsers distinguish from merely displaying data (like an off-site-pointing form that targets an iframe) and allowing JS to deeply inspect the data. this is to cut down on zombie nets, prevent deep-link image rebranding, etc. really, you're right: most uses would be harmless, but rules are rules and 3rd-party assets are not supposed to be available to JS. they do the same on harmless CSSRules...

Comment: In the bad-old-days, overflow errors let malicious code run and image processing was one way to trigger overflows. Today, the idea is that html5 canvas can both read img elements (drawImage) and export data (`getImageData` and `toDataURL`) so it can be a conduit to steal confidential information. For example, if you're viewing an image of your bank statement, malicious code can create an un-noticeable in-memory canvas, draw your bank statement image onto the canvas, serialize your bank statement pixels and send the serialized pixel data to a thief. All un-noticed by you.

Comment: Wait a sec, wouldn't the malicious code if it were able to get onto the page possibly be able to do that anyway? So long as the proposed image for the bank statement was on the same domain as the website the malicious code snuck onto, it would still be able to get the image data and send it out.

Comment: Yes, but if you can get the code to the bank's servers you presumably already have full access to them so you can just take whatever you want.

Comment: Makes sense, but that is not the only way it can happen. Ads and browser add-ons or extensions are a couple of more ways that malicious code can sneak into pages. However it happens, it seems to me like once it is there, it has all the ability it needs to serialize an image and send it away.

Comment: There is one thing I have realized from this conversation though. Given the bank statement example, the image *could* be served off a separate domain on the bank's website. In that case, then CORS really would prevent malicious code from stealing the customer's information. I guess it all comes down to the design pattern. Interesting stuff here.

Comment: @MikeC oh i see, to be clear, you mean since the malicious script's origin is <url 1>, it can't inspect images in <the url you are visiting>, so if a bank accidentally links some foreign api, and the foreign api becomes malicious, it can't start collecting screenshots of visitors activities. Foreign scripts accessing local images is sketchy, but I'm not quite sure why current-location-hosted scripts can't access foreign images.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This protects users from having private data exposed by using images to pull information from remote web sites without permission.

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think that makes any sense. Users can still have private data exposed by pulling images from another website with or without the website's permission. It's called a tracking pixel.

Comment: @JoshuaDannemann Yes but as markE pointed out, that's not the only way to extract data. Imagine you have a bank statement open, which only you can view because of some kind of authentication header, but then a 3rd party creates a canvas element and inserts that image into the canvas. They could then convert that to a blob and send it back to home base if the canvas wasn't marked as "tainted".

Comment: @JoshuaDannemann The difference is that the site that provides the tracking pixel is the "attacker". Pulling a tracking pixeI from a 3rd party site doesn't make much sense; the only party that can read the tracking data is the site where you pulled it from.

Comment: @MikeC Oh wow! Great example! I did not think about that, but this is why I was asking the question. I really wanted to know why / how it could be a security risk.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, not an answer to the question but ...

FYI: It's not

> Either the server can set the http header access-control-allow-origin: "*", or allow a developer to set the crossDomain attribute for the image to "anonymous"/"use-credentials".

**BOTH are required**.

You need to set `crossOrigin` because it changes the request the browser makes to the server for the image. But even if you don't set it, and the server sends the CORS headers anyway the browser will still not let you use the image unless you had set `crossOrigin`.

You can see it in this example, two images, both of which receive CORS headers from the server but the browser only lets one work.

```js
loadAndDrawImage("https://i.imgur.com/fRdrkI1.jpg", "");
loadAndDrawImage("https://i.imgur.com/Vn68XJQ.jpg");

function loadAndDrawImage(url, crossOrigin) {
  const img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() { 
    log("For image", crossOrigin !== undefined ? "WITH" : "without", "crossOrigin set");
    try {
      const ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1);
      log("canvas still clean:", name);
    } catch (e) {
      error(name, ":", e);
    }
    log(" ");
  };  
  if (crossOrigin !== undefined) {
    img.crossOrigin = crossOrigin;
  }
  img.src = url;
}

function logImpl(color, ...args) {
  const elem = document.createElement("pre");
  elem.textContent = [...args].join(" ");
  elem.style.color = color;
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
}

function log(...args) {
  logImpl("green", ...args);
}

function error(...args) {
  logImpl("red", ...args);
}
```

```css
pre { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<div>check headers in devtools</div>
```

If you check the header you'll see they both received CORS headers but only one image worked.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This security measure can be solved without making it the elephant in the room. In the server of the images change `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to the origin that you are planning to create the canvas. And set it only available for the images, not other resources.
Later on by adding `crossorigin` attribute as `anonynous` or just `""` and have the problem solved without creating a large security break.

Example: In Apache you can add this to you `.htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        <FilesMatch "\.(cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|png|svgz?|webp)$">
            SetEnvIf Origin ":" IS_CORS
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://yourapp.com [or just *]" env=IS_CORS
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I understand how to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers, although, I did not have the necessary access at the time.