# Konvajs - Layer.toImage() return null instead of the image data

Tags: reactjs, cors, konvajs

I am currently working on a layer of the stage that gets exported to a png file on a button event, it is working, but just until I added a Logo as an Image class to the layer.

Without adding the Image element:

```
layer.toImage({
   callback: function(img) { //img = "base_64 image data".
     console.log(img.src);
   }
});
```

With the Image element:

```
layer.toImage({
   callback: function(img) { //img = null
     console.log(img.src); // Error: src of null.
   }
});
```

Here, the app crashes and I can´t find the problem. I tried to add and remove the image and then export the image, works perfectly. I only have this problem when an image element is drawn in the Layer.

Any ideas why this is happening?

**Update**

Code example:

```
var myLayer= this.refs.layer;
myLayer.children.forEach(element => {
  if (element.attrs.elementType === "text"){
    if (element.isVisible()){
      element.visible(false);
      hiddenElements.push(element.id);
    }
  }
});

myLayer.toImage({
  callback: function(img) { //If image is drawn to the leyer img = null
    *Ajax function here*    //Else img has base64 info of the leyer
  },
  mimeType: "image/png"
});
```

I then set all hiddenElements back to true and the stage gets back to its initial state.

Comment: Do you have any warnings in the console? Can you provide a simple demo?

Comment: Looks like it is a problem with CORS images.

Comment: @lavrton Warning: Unable to get data URL. Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

Comment: Ok, that was it, CORS images tainted my canvas. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else coming to this and wondering about 'CORS', [Wikipedia introduces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) CORS as

> Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that allows
>   restricted resources (e.g. fonts) on a web page to be requested from
>   another domain outside the domain from which the first resource was
>   served. A web page may freely embed cross-origin images,
>   stylesheets, scripts, iframes, and videos. Certain "cross-domain"
>   requests, notably Ajax requests, are forbidden by default by the
>   same-origin security policy.

What this means in practice is that a canvas cannot process an image from another (non-CORS enabled) domain into a blob. If it tries the browser will force the 'Tainted canvas' error which you can observe in the browser console.

There is a pithy explanation of why this is so in this reply by [Mike C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/371184/mike-c) to  [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020259/why-cors-on-images-with-html-canvas), which I will copy here for brevity.

> Imagine you have a bank statement open, which only you can view
>   because of some kind of authentication header, but then a 3rd party
>   creates a canvas element and inserts that image into the canvas. They
>   could then convert that to a blob and send it back to home base if the
>   canvas wasn't marked as "tainted"

It turns out that the benefits of canvas are also potentially pitfalls. Or as Yoda might say *'Powerful you have become, the dark side I sense in you.'*