# Aframe / Three.js Tainted canvases may not be loaded

Tags: three.js, cross-domain, webgl, aframe, same-origin-policy

Im building an app with Aframe that requires fetching images saved onto AWS.

I was getting consistent cors rejection, and after resolving that, my images are passing cors but SOMETIMES they are not, I then utilized asset caching to render the images and the error has changed from mentioning cors to Tainted canvases

[image]

Im thinking that cors is effected by the clients internet speed or location?

Im also using aframe react and im wondering if react-rerenders on startup are causing the issue.

Comment: You need to request CORS permission **AND** the server needs to grant that permission. See: https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-cors-permission.html, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020259/why-cors-on-images-with-html-canvas, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087757/three-js-and-loading-a-cross-domain-image, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30945945/tainted-canvases-may-not-be-loaded-cross-domain-issue-with-webgl-textures

Comment: For me adding crossorigin="anonymous" solved it.  If your images are on s3, I think it already has a valid cross-domain CORS policy, so all it took was the attribute in the <img> tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to have `<img crossorigin="anonymous">` set, and try without the React layer (which I don't recommend using anymore for perf and scalability reasons for VR, and seeing it mishandled most of the time).