# Change Color of Stop Sign to Blue?

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing, colors

I was given basic code from my teacher and I have since modified it a little (and honestly probably messed it up). It is supposed to display a second image when you click the button, and the second image is also supposed to have its colors converted. I have tried everything, but cannot seem to get a second image to show or change any colors. I will put the code and image that we are supposed to be putting below. The color that we are supposed to change is the entire stop sign, the red parts, is blue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  background-color: #000000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="849" height="565"></canvas> 

<script>
var img = new Image(); 

img.src = "stop sign.jpg";

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); // id found in the canvas id tag 'canvas'
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 

img.onload = function() {
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0); // execute drawImage statement after image is loaded
}
function convert() 
{
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // I do not know what to put here in order to gather the data of the image that was originally made?
    var data = imageData.data;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i +=4) 
    {
        //# check if RED channel has pixel values in range of 200 to 255
        if( ( data[i+0] >= 200) && ( data[i+0] <= 255 ) ) 
        {
            //if such pixel found in range then change that pixel color to...
            data[i + 2] = data[i + 0];  //use red level as blue level
            data[i + 1] = 0;    //no green 
            data[i + 0] = 0; //no red
        }
    } 

    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0); // this is supposed to produce a second image right next to the original image, but I cannot seem to get this to function either. This image is also supposed to be manipulated to have the stop sign blue
}

</script>
<p><button onclick="convert()">Change</button></p>
</body>
</html>
```

[STOP SIGN IMAGE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHc5v.jpg)

Comment: Any progress? Did the answer work for you? If not try the new edit (using as `function convert()` ).

Comment: The answer did not work, unfortunately. No second image showed up either (when you click the "Change" button, a second image is supposed to appear with the edits). I will try the new edit and see if it works. I'm sorry for not updating on the progress! I've been very busy haha.

Comment: @VC.One I tried using your new edits as well as making some other edits but made no progress in changing anything. I posted the edits above in my post along with some comments along side. I am still not getting any results and I genuinely do not know why!

Comment: correct: `var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);`

Comment: correct: `ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);`

Comment: correct : `<p><button onclick="convert()">Change</button></p>`

Comment: Ideally your `canvas` should have same size (w / h) as the input image...

Comment: @VC.One So I tried making the changes, and still nothing happened. It just shows the picture against the black background with a button that does nothing when clicked. I even tried just inputting the width and the height for the var imageData instead of using canvas.width, but even that didn't change anything. I changed the numbers around for the color variables (just using 255 for blue), but that didn't work either. I feel like this is a lost cause haha

Comment: What browser are you using? Are your files tested as local (hard drive) or running from online HTTPS? If running the html/JS code from a non-web server there might be a security issue... Open the **Developer Tools** of your browser and go to the **Console** tab, does it show any error about canvas?

Comment: @VC.One Firefox, tested locally. These are the canvas errors: ``` The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.
Uncaught DOMException: The operation is insecure.
Uncaught DOMException: The operation is insecure. 
Uncaught DOMException: The operation is insecure. 
Uncaught DOMException: The operation is insecure. ```

Comment: Don't worry I haven't forgotten about your issue. Basically browsers don't like files being loaded from local storage (it has to be from online). If loading from local, the user must choose the file themselves to show they are giving permission your JS code to read its data. So you need to use the **File Browser** API. You can research & practice for now, I'll show you a working code for your local file issue when I get a chance later today.

Comment: @VC.One Okay, so I had class and my teacher ran my code (I still cannot see my code and I still have not found a way to get it to work. I do not understand why we are doing work that needs to work around web browser security procedures). So, the stop sign turns entirely blue, but so do some clouds and shadows. Only the red parts should be blue, the white of the STOP and outline should still be seen, and there should still be some texture on the stop sign. I will try to mess with it but if I could see what I was doing it would be great haha

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem with:

```
function convert() 
{
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,849,565);
    var data = imageData.data;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i +=4) 
    {
        //# check if RED channel has pixel values in range of 200 to 255
        if( ( data[i+0] >= 200) && ( data[i+0] <= 255 ) ) 
        {
            //if such pixel found in range then change that pixel color to...
            data[i + 2] = data[i + 0];  //use red level as blue level
            data[i + 1] = 0;    //no green 
            data[i + 0] = 0; //no red
        }
    } 

    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 500, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having problems with canvas because of [browser security issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020259/why-cors-on-images-with-html-canvas).

Whilst a media `<tag>` can display image/video from any link, it becomes an issue for code that wants to "copy" or "edit" the visuals if the media source is **not from your own website** (*ie:* your https server).

From a hard drive, a webpage can have an `<img>` to load images (which is "safe" because all is controlled by the browser itself), but JS code cannot edit those images, without user permission.

To allow **user-given permission**: You must use the **File Browser** API. When a user-selects a specific file they are agreeing to give access to its data (pixels become editable).

**Solution**:

- I simply create a blank `<a>` tag which will later have an `<image>` tag added by JS code (*ie:* dynamically added).
- The image tag will use the selected file as its `.src` (it is in **Blob** format, but you can also use an **Array** of image bytes if you need to).
- The convert function checks if any pixel has its Red value (level) set within a specific range (210 and above) and also at same time the Blue values is smaller than 165.
- You can fine tune your color tolerance with the `IF` statement . Experiment with editing Red minimum (from 210 to now start at 220) or editing Blue. What happens if you add Green to the tolerance / range check (*eg:* `if( (red > 210) && (blue < 165) && (green < 100) )`).

You'll have to check in a photo editor the expected R-G-B ranges of your stop sign.

Try to study from this example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head> <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"> </head>

<body>

<div style="z-index: 1; overflow:hidden; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 50px">
<p> Choose an Image file...</p>
<input type="file" id="choose_media" accept=".gif, .jpg, .png" />
</div>

<div style="z-index: 1; overflow:hidden; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 570px">
<p> Apply Image Effect...</p>
<button id="btn_change" >Change Color</button>
</div>

<!-- aTag is container for user-selected image --> 
<div style="z-index: 1; overflow:hidden; position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 50px">
<a id="aTag"> </a>
</div>

<!-- canvas is container for effect's result image --> 
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="334" style="z-index: 5; overflow:hidden; position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 570px">
</canvas>


<script>

var file; 
var reader;
var tmpElement; //# is reference to aTag for holding image content.
var file_Blob; //# is reference to file BLOB (data of selected file).

//## set canvas width / height values
var img_w = 500; var img_h = 334;

//## temp Color values
var temp_R = 0; var temp_G = 0; var temp_B = 0;

//# define event for button "select file"...
document.getElementById('choose_media').addEventListener('change', onFileSelected, false);

//# define event for button "change effect"...
document.getElementById('btn_change').addEventListener('click', convert, false);

//# define Canvas and its Context
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = img_w; canvas.height = img_h;

function onFileSelected(evt) 
{
    file = evt.target.files[0]; //# access to selected file
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file); //# load selected file
    
    //# create elements
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) 
    {
        if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) 
        {
             //# update file path...
            file_Blob = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(file);
            
            
            //# remove any other existing elements in "aTag"...
            var container = document.getElementById("aTag");
            container.removeChild(container.childNodes[0]); 
            
            //# create HTML5 image element for "aTag"...
            tmpElement = document.createElement( "img");
            tmpElement.setAttribute("id", "img");
            tmpElement.setAttribute("width", img_w);
            tmpElement.setAttribute("height", img_h);

            //# set "load complete" check then make draw to canvas
            tmpElement.addEventListener("load", () => 
            {
                //alert("img loaded");
                ctx.drawImage(tmpElement, 0, 0, img_w, img_h); //draws rescaled
            });
                        
            //# add newly created HTML5 image into the "aTag" element.
            tmpElement.setAttribute("src", file_Blob);
            container.appendChild(tmpElement);  
        }
    };
}


function convert()
{
    //# is already previously drawn by "load" function (but can do it here)...
    //# tmpElement is the (source container of) user-selected image.
    //ctx.drawImage(tmpElement, 0, 0, 500, 334);
    
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // I do not know what to put here in order to gather the data of the image that was originally made?
    var data = imageData.data;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i +=4) 
    {
        temp_R = data[i + 0];
        
        temp_B = data[i + 2];

        //# condition: Change color whenever... 
        //# if RED channel has a pixel value above 210.
        //# AND if BLUE channel has a pixel value smaller than 165.
        if( ( data[i+0] > 210) && ( data[i+2] < 165 ) ) 
        {
            //if such pixel found in range then change that pixel color to...
            data[i + 0] = temp_B; //# Red = use Blue level as Red level
            //data[i + 1] = data[i + 1]; //# Grn = no edit of Green 
            data[i + 2] = temp_R; //# Blu = use Red level as Blue level
        }
    } 

    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```